# Java Mail API to search for particular address

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

i would like to search my inbox through java api filtering particular address...
For Eg., i would like to search all the mails from particular emailid say john@gmail.com
and do a sysout.

```
Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
store.connect(host, user, password);
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, true);
Message unreadMessages[] = emailFolder.search(unseenFlagTerm);

for (int i = unreadMessages.length-1; i > 0 ; i--) {
  System.out.println("Subject : " + unreadMessages[i].getSubject());
  System.out.println("From : " + unreadMessages[i].getFrom()[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the code you posted works, using a simple loop, it would be something like:

```
FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, true);
Message[] unreadMessages = emailFolder.search(unseenFlagTerm);
Address searchFrom = new InternetAddress("john@gmail.com");

for (int i = unreadMessages.length-1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    Message message = unreadMessages[i];

    if(Arrays.asList(message.getFrom()).contains(searchFrom)) {
        System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`FromTerm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/search/FromTerm.html):

```
FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, true);
FromTerm fromTerm = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("john@gmail.com"));
SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(unseenFlagTerm, fromTerm);

Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(searchTerm);

for (int i = messages.length-1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
}
```

Comment: Instead of searching in the loop can't we directly filter while retrieving using FlagTerm or any other way?